# Could you help me understand what the expression "as a proportion of" means?

Tags: expressions

I was reading a book called Enlightenment and found a sentence that I didn't fully understand. The sentence reads as follows:
"How many people are victims of violence as a proportion of the number of people alive?"
By "as a proportion of", does the author mean "compared to"? I would be glad if you could help me out.

Answer (score 3):

The author means "divided by." In other words, what is the *ratio* of victims of violence to world population?

See "proportion," [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proportion), sense 3:

> the relation of one part to another or to the whole with respect to magnitude, quantity, or degree : RATIO